# How to write lambda with some parameters not be used in Clojure?

Tags: lambda, clojure

```
(reduce (fn [z a] (inc z)) 0 coll)
```

This expression is used to measure the length of `coll`, but how to transform the `fn` into lambda function? Noticing parameter `a` is not used in the `fn` body, I have tried `#(inc %1)` but it does not work.

Comment: It is a lambda function already, so the transformation you have to make is the identity transformation.

Comment: it's also common to write `(fn [z _] (inc z))` to indicate for the unused param

Comment: Any reason you're doing that rather than using `count`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is technically possible to do this as follows:

```
(reduce #(do %2 (inc %1)) 0 [1 2 3])
;= 3
```

`#(do %2 (inc %1))` produces exactly the same bytecode as `(fn [x _] (inc x))`. `%2` here is a reference to a local in statement context; a reference to a local cannot by itself cause a side effect; thus, it is not reflected in the resulting bytecode at all. See end of this answer for the actual bytecode.

This is, of course, a weird way to write it and `(fn [x _] (inc x))` is preferable as a matter of style.

---

Incidentally, the term "lambda function" typically means "anonymous function", or a function introduced inline in expression context, as opposed to at top level. `#(…)` would typically be called a "function literal". (In many contexts the two terms are equivalent, but in Clojure `(fn […] …)` doesn't use any special "function syntax" at the lexical/reader level, whereas `#(…)` is indeed special reader syntax for introducing anonymous functions.)

---

`Object invoke(Object, Object)` disassembly:

```
;; (fn [x _] (inc x))
  public java.lang.Object invoke(java.lang.Object x, java.lang.Object _);
    0  aload_1 [x]
    1  aconst_null
    2  astore_1 [x]
    3  invokestatic clojure.lang.Numbers.inc(java.lang.Object) : java.lang.Number [33]
    6  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 1]
        [pc: 3, line: 1]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 6] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.Object
        [pc: 0, pc: 6] local: x index: 1 type: java.lang.Object
        [pc: 0, pc: 6] local: _ index: 2 type: java.lang.Object

}

;; #(do %2 (inc %1))
  public java.lang.Object invoke(java.lang.Object p1__3703_SHARP_, java.lang.Object p2__3702_SHARP_);
    0  aload_1 [p1__3703_SHARP_]
    1  aconst_null
    2  astore_1 [p1__3703_SHARP_]
    3  invokestatic clojure.lang.Numbers.inc(java.lang.Object) : java.lang.Number [33]
    6  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 1]
        [pc: 3, line: 1]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 6] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.Object
        [pc: 0, pc: 6] local: p1__3703_SHARP_ index: 1 type: java.lang.Object
        [pc: 0, pc: 6] local: p2__3702_SHARP_ index: 2 type: java.lang.Object

}
```

The other methods are also the same – these ones are responsible for the actual calls to these functions.

Answer (score 4):

Clojure works out how many arguments a lambda function should take by finding the largest numbered `%` parameter that is within it's body.  In your case using `#(inc %1)` does not work, because it will create a function that accepts one argument, but `reduce` requires a function that accepts two.

If you are defining a function that does not use one of it's later arguments, then you should stick to a `fn` form.

Comment: em, further more...A function that uses all of it's arguments can be defined either in `fn` form or lambda form? That is right? And how can I define `(mapcat (fn [a] [a a]) [1 2 3])` in lambda form?

Comment: `(mapcat #(vector %1 %1) [1 2 3])` if you look at the `(macroexpand '#([%1 %1]))` you'll see what it does and why I used `vector`